# Epoxy over Self leveling Compound Cracks

Tags: self-leveling-concrete, epoxy

I'm trying to put flooring down in a kitchen but I ran into some issues and I'm looking for general advice.  The floor started with old but decent condition plywood with some old patchy black adhesive on top.  It was pretty level, but the adhesive gave it some bumpiness and it wasnt budging.  I poured self leveling compound over about 300sqft (28sq m) at 1/6" (~4mm) depth on top of the plywood after rolling down some primer.  This produced some hairline cracks and one trouble spot that crumbled a little where I misjudged the terrain slightly.  I decided to try to roll down some 2-part epoxy (RustOleum EpoxySheild Basement Tint) anyhow hoping it might fill in these spots, but the cracks remained.  I think the hairline cracks are due to the plywood moving around a little and another coat of epoxy seems unlikely to stop that.  I assume all of these cracks will allow water infiltration and the floor will fall apart within months which is unnacceptable.

I think the only way to resolve this is to put vinyl or wood planks down.  At least the surface is pretty smooth now.  Attempting to patch and recoat isnt going to work is it?  Do I need to patch the crumbly parts before putting down planks?  If so, what product exactly would work for that?  If I wanted to raise a couple square feet like 1mm higher, what product would be appropriate?

Thank you

[Pics](https://imgur.com/a/PNKcsM4)

Comment: Is the self leveling stuff intended to be used as a walking surface anyway? Typically that stuff is supposed to be used below something like your vinyl or wood planks.

Comment: Correct, the self leveling compound was supposed to be underlayment, not a working surface.  I had hoped the epoxy would provide the surface, but all the cracks make it pretty unlikely in this case since the plywood moves so much.

Comment: What type of flooring are you planning to install?

Comment: I'm leaning toward lifeproof hardwood or linoleum planks at this point.

Comment: If you need to raise up some areas by only 1mm, that's a simple matter of doubling up whatever you use as a pad in those areas.

Comment: @KMJ that depends whether the product requires underlay; Lifeproof typically has it attached, so additional underlay is not necessary.  OP, I suspect your subfloor is a bit too flexible for a product like epoxy that cures pretty rigid.  Perhaps something like DAP Flexible Floor Patch and Leveler, or equivalent?  Do some research.

Comment: Even if it's not necessary, it's probably the quickest-easiest way to fix something like a 1mm low spot.